# how to link to dynamically generated page in jsp

Tags: jsp

I am new to server side programming. I have a final year project on Online Book sales management system. I want to know how to generate a dynamic page for each of book images clicked for purchase. I mean to say that if user requests for any book X, how is it possible to generate a page which shows its all details, image etc information. what kind of url should I use?

Comment: Can you give mode details ?

Comment: It is an online book sales management system, where people can buy books online. I want to know how to get book information from the data base and display it in another page, whenever any user clicks on any book image or link. I mean to say that how do I link both the pages because I don't know in prior which book will user click on. The summary of my problem is how to know which book has been clicked and then take user to details page of that book.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the unique identifier of the book as request parameter or request path info and have a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) to perform the data lookup in the `doGet()` method based on the identifier, store it in the request scope and forward to a JSP file which generates all the necessary HTML.

E.g. as request parameter `/book?id=123` with this servlet

```
@WebServlet("/book")
public class BookServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private BookService service;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Book book = service.find(request.getParameter("id"));
        request.setAttribute("book", book);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/book.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Or as request path info `/book/123` with this servlet

```
@WebServlet("/book/*")
public class BookServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private BookService service;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Book book = service.find(request.getPathInfo().substring(1));
        request.setAttribute("book", book);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/book.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Either way, the `/WEB-INF/book.jsp` could just look like this the usual way.

```
<p>Title: <c:out value="${book.title}" /></p>
<p>Author: <c:out value="${book.author}" /></p>
<p>Summary: <c:out value="${book.summary}" /></p>
```

In order to generate those links to the servlet, just loop over a `List<Book>` in `/WEB-INF/books.jsp` as follows, assuming that you want URLs like `/book/123`:

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach items="${books}" var="book">
        <li>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/book/${book.id}">
                View book with title: <c:out value="${book.title}" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I don't understand -> <c:forEach items="${books}" var="book"> code. what exactly is this?

Comment: That's just a loop over `List<Book>`. It's like `for (Book book : books) {}` in normal Java code. Click the "servlet" link in my answer for more examples.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming it's a small scale project.
First maintain a database for your books.. give each of 'em an unique id.
If you are display all the common details like... published on, price, book name, author, reviews, rating.... Then you don't need to worry.. Create a common JSP Page to display the indo based on an uniqueId...

**jsp say: books.jsp**

```
<form name="books" action="getInfo.jsp">
    <a href="YourJSP/?bookid=pass_an_id_for_your_bookX">Book X(Image)</a> //Book X
    <a href="YourJSP/?bookid=pass_an_id_for_your_bookY">Book Y(Image)</a> //Book Y 
    <a href="YourJSP/?bookid=pass_an_id_for_your_bookZ">Book Z(Image)</a> //Book Z
....
.... an on..
</form>
```

?bookid will be your paramid.
pass_an_id_for_your_bookX will be your unique id of your bookX stored in database.

**inside your 2nd JSP say: getInfo.jsp**

Design your JSP for presentation, to diplay info about your BookX / BookY w.r.t to bookId
In your JSP get the value of bookId and query the DB...

```
        String bookId = request.getParameter("bookid"):
        //This will get the value of your bookId for BookX

        //Connect to your DB
        //Use PreparedStatement or StoredProcedure to make a query pass your bookId in where condition.
```

Rest is simple, By Querying the database you will all the usual values ie. published on, price, book name, author, reviews, rating... and display them accordingly in your JSP page..

```
      <%
      Connection con = null;
      PreparedStatement pst = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;

      String BookName=null;
      String AuthorName=null;
      String Price=null;
      String Rating=null;
      try {

      Class.forName(driver);
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);

      String sql =
      "select * from BOOKS_TABLE where bookId =?";
      pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setString(1, bookId);

      rs = pst.executeQuery();

      while (rs.next()) {
      BookName = rs.getString(1);
      AuthorName = rs.getString(2);
      Price = rs.getString(3);
      Rating = rs.getString(4);

      }
      // 1 , 2, 3... denotes column numbers
      } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      }
    } 
    %>
```

Now you got all your values.. Well, display them accordingly..

```
       <%=BookName%>
       <%=AuthorName%>
       <%=Price%>
       <%=Rating%>
```

**A Note:** Scriplets(Java Code) are not encouraged in JSP page.. You may want to check into Beans or JSTL. I'm just giving you an IDEA!

ALL THE BEST

Comment: This code exposes a lot of bad practices, the worst being DB resource leaking.

Comment: Hey Balus, I know I gave him 'the NOTE'. The kid is working on a final year project... now I can't expect him to be Pro JSTL, HQL or Spring MVC, can I? So, I just gave him the IDEA and warned him with a NOTE. 
Oh! and my bad I forgot to close my RS and DB Connection :D was in a hurry. Have a good day!